# Macro to combine weekend date data and delete previous data

Tags: vba, excel

I have data over 4 columns with the first columns "A" as a date column then the following columns "B,C,D" as data. I am trying to create a macro that will search for the dates that are weekends and add them to Monday's data then delete the weekend date and data from the overall data. This is my code so far:

```
Sub NamedRange()

Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim newDate As Integer
Dim NumberOfRows As Range
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim lastRow2 As Variant
Set Rng1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A20")


Dim date1 As String
Dim dat As Date
Dim newPrice As Double


Set RgSales = Range("MyRange")
For i = 1 To RgSales.Rows.Count
For j = 1 To RgSales.Columns.Count

dat = RgSales.Cells(i, j)

date1 = WeekdayName(Weekday(dat))
    If (date1 = "Saturday" Or date1 = "Sunday") Then
        newDate = (RgSales.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value) + (RgSales.Cells(i, j + 1).Value)
        RgSales.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value = newDate
        newPrice = (RgSales.Cells(i + 1, j + 2).Value) + (RgSales.Cells(i, j + 2).Value)
        RgSales.Cells(i + 1, j + 2).Value = newPrice
        RgSales.Cells(i, j).Select
        Selection.Delete
        RgSales.Cells(i, j + 1).Select
        Selection.Delete
        RgSales.Cells(i, j + 2).Select
        Selection.Delete
End If
    Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

I am having problems with the Range, I just want it to end on the last row of data, and after the macro is run delete all the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when you delete rows from a range, you want to loop backwards.  Once you delete a row, all the rows below it change relative to the range (row 18 becomes row 17) and that can mess up your counters.  Here's an example that I think does what you want.

```
Sub ConsolidateWeekends()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim lDayOffset As Long

    'Define the range to consolidate
    Set rRng = Sheet3.Range("A1:A20")

    'Always loop backward when deleting rows or
    'the counter will get messed up
    For i = rRng.Rows.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
        Set rCell = rRng.Cells(i, 1)

        'Define the offset that will return the Monday following the date
        If Weekday(rCell.Value) = vbSaturday Then
            lDayOffset = 2
        ElseIf Weekday(rCell.Value) = vbSunday Then
            lDayOffset = 1
        Else
            lDayOffset = 0
        End If

        If lDayOffset > 0 Then
            'Find the cell with the Monday in question
            Set rFound = rRng.Find(CDate(rCell.Value + lDayOffset), , xlValues, xlWhole)

            'if there is a cell with that Monday
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                'Add the current dates B and C values to the Monday B and C values
                For j = 1 To 2
                    rFound.Offset(0, j).Value = rFound.Offset(0, j).Value + rCell.Offset(0, j).Value
                Next j
                'Delete the Sat or Sun row
                rCell.EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```